# adding code to jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slice of jquery code that I would like to be able to change when desired:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        // tpeck
        events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/somebody%40gmail.com/public/basic',

        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

    });

});
```

It's that address above.

I don't know where to begin, but I'd like to be able to enter a new address online - in an input box, I guess - and have the code change to reflect this.

If anyone has seen anything similar done, I would be grateful for a link or clue as to how to go about it.

---

OK, so...using @Outlooker's idea:

```
var myvalue = $('#myinput').val();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    // tpeck
    events: 'myvalue',
```

I can save the contents of the input field to a mySQL database, and on page load the input is automatically retrieved and displays, but it must be out of sequence because the calendar doesn't display from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this might help you mate.. :) Suppose if you have an `input` field like

```
<input type="text" id="myInput"/>
```

you could get the value of that field by using

```
var myvalue = $('#myInput').val();
```

and then pass this value to the address.

Note:Do validate your fields mate.. :)